# Issue when trying to send a newly created component in Translation through workflow

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow, translation-manager, worldserver

I have written a code to send the components to World server for translation through workflow. For existing component it is working fine but when I am trying with a newly created component it is giving below error-

> Translation Job id: 81 Translation Job title: Workflow Item Source
>   Publication URI: tcm:0-5-1 Source Publication title: 200 Master
>   Content (ENG)
>
> The item is shared.
>
> at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.CoreServiceProxy.HandleCoreServiceFault(FaultException`1
>   ex)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.CoreServiceProxy.CallWithErrorHandling(Action
>   callMethod, String traceFormatString, Object[] traceParameters)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData(TcmUri
>   itemId, String applicationKey, XDocument document)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TcmItems.TcmItemTranslationInfo.SaveTranslationInfo(UserContext
>   userContext)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.InternalFinalizeTmsJob(TranslationJob
>   job, TranslationSystemJobRequest jobRequest, IEnumerable`1
>   itemRequests, HashSet`1 uploadedLanguageIds)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.FinalizeTmsJob(TranslationJob
>   job, TranslationSystemJobRequest jobRequest, IEnumerable`1
>   itemRequests)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.ProcessClient(TranslationJob
>   job, String clientId, List`1 resolvedItems)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.Process()
>   at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.ServiceTask.ThreadMethod()

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translation an item requires it to be localized. SDL Tridion 2013-SP1 does not support localizing an item before it has reached V1.

A common workaround is to create a workflow that check if it is a new item in the first step. If it is, it completes the workflow (creating a v1) and starts the workflow once more.

SDL Web 8 supports localizing items (and sending them for translation) before they reach V1. Do notice that localizing an item before it reach V1 will still create a V1 item in the child publication (unless the child item enters workflow as well).